# Can a forms total pixels across the screen be changed?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a program that has a little ship flying across the screen. And of course if the ship is flying right (90 degrees) its X:Y ratio will be 1:0... but if its flying at 95 degrees the ratio will be 0.94444444444:0.05555555555... and then if the ship is moving at a speed of 2 pixels per tick (16ms)... the X movement will be rounded up to 2 and the Y movement will be about 0.1, and it cant move 0.1 pixels... How do i get around this? Or how do i make the form a lot more pixels so i can speed the ship up, so its movement wont be 0.something.

Comment: How is the little ship being drawn?

Comment: You can draw an Image using floating point values. The approximation is half a pixel. If you calculate the slope between the two points (or simply use the formula `float x = (p1.X * (1.0F - position) + p2.X * position) - offset.X; float y = (p1.Y * (1.0F - position) + p2.Y * position) - offset.Y;`, where `offset` is the center point of the Image and `position` is a value between `.0F` and `1.0F`, to increment by `.01F` each time the Timer ticks), the Image is moved smoothly, no matter what the slope.

Comment: Of course I wrote it in C#. In VB.Net, it would be: `dim x as single = (p1.X * (1.0F - position) + p2.X * position) - offset.X dim y as single = (p1.Y * (1.0F - position) + p2.Y * position) - offset.Y dim p = new PointF(x, y)` -- As mentioned, you need to post your code.

Comment: @jimi That would work, just problem is my ship is an imagebox not a drawing. But thanks anyway

Comment: That does work, it's how you move a shape along the line that connects two points. You move its center point, not the edges. It doesn't matter if you draw an Image (that's what you should do) or use a Control to show it (that's not what you should do - no idea what an `imagebox` is, you didn't even specify what UI platform you're using).

Comment: @Jimi ... I dont understand :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of increasing the size of the form I changed way I thought of the ship mevement... I just Maintained the real position elsewhere and only calculated the actual pixel position when rendering. This way after a few frames or so it will move, like watching a radar screen or slowed-down video.